# is it possible to set absolute position of ionic modal?

Tags: ionic-framework, css-position

I am using ionic [modalPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

but i want to have the modal full width appearing from the buttom like this in [materialise.css](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) ( check the modal buttom sheet style).

how can i do that with ionic ?
There is a [discussion here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-set-ionic-modal-bottom-property/22501) but still it was about centring and not absolute buttom so this did not work

```
 .modal-center {
  position : absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Would be great if you offer an edit to this [codePen](https://codepen.io/ionic/pen/gblny)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you think. Add this css:

```
@media (min-width: 680px){
  ion-modal-view.modal {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0% !important;
    bottom: 0% !important;
    left: 0% !important;
    min-height: 240px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: but why have you added @media. is it needed ?

Comment: No, it's not needed. I put it there just in case you have other CSS code for the modal on a device whose width is less than 680px